# active record 3 select with nested tables

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, nested

i've got these classes:

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :offers
    #table has an integer-column 'season'
end

class Broker < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :offers
end

class Offer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :game
    belongs_to :broker
end
```

and i want to select all offers from one broker where the season of the game is 2009, for example.
i tried

```
Broker.first.offers.joins(:game).where(:game => {:season => 2009}).each do |o|
    puts o.inspect
end
```

but that gives me

> `rescue in log': PGError: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "game" (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
>   LINE 1: ...games" ON "games"."id" = "offers"."game_id" WHERE "game"."se...
>   : SELECT "offers".* FROM "offers" INNER JOIN "games" ON "games"."id" = "offers"."game_id" WHERE "game"."season" = 2009 AND ("offers".broker_id = 1)

how should i do such selects, or where can i find more information on this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change `where(:game => {:season => 2009})` to `where(:games => {:season => 2009})`

Your table is named "games" (in plural) and the hash key in the where condition should be the table name, not the association name.

Comment: I love you, I've been searching for this little issue for a good few hours. Thank you.